# How to convert entire excel sheet from decimal to binary values?

Tags: excel

I have a dataset with 25000 records and 10 features at each index all these records are in decimal and i want to convert it to binary values, i tried the DEC2BIN function in Microsoft Excel and I've tried to drag the function all over the worksheet but it always gives me #Value or #REF. is there any idea, thanks.

Comment: The numbers are already in binary inside the computer, but it shows them in decimal for your convenience. Or if that is not what you meant, please show us a small example of what you have and what you want.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks for your response i understand that all i need to do is to display the whole dataset in binary not decimal

Comment: @AndrewMorton here it is row1 5   9    8   6   7   20 here's the first row i want to convert the row1 to the binary representation instead of decimal

Comment: @ziadx123: please edit your question rather than put new info in comments

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you wish to convert and run this short macro:

```
Sub WaitaBit()
    Dim r As Range, v As Variant
    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Value
        If IsNumeric(v) And v <> "" Then
            s = Application.WorksheetFunction.Dec2Bin(v, 10)
            Do While Left(s, 1) = "0"
                s = Mid(s, 2)
            Loop
            r.Value = "'" & s
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

So:

[image]

will become:

[image]

This will handle most "small" integers.